# Add to display Feature Class (GDB) with variable name

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, feature-class, display

I have a model in modelbuilder and I'm trying to display the output with the same name as the input (using Parse Path Name) which something like "C12345_BIRDS" so I want to add "_FINAL" to this. If I set a concrete name everything is displayed properly including the symbology but if I set the output name as %Value%_FINAL the feature class is created as well but not displayed. The parameters and tick-boxes are correctly set.

I have read somewhere this is a ESRI bug and it has to be solved by using Code Block box and arcpy.mapping in Calculate Field, that I used right after I created the output I'm interested in.

I dont know what to write in there to force my model to display a feature class with variable name.

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you elaborate more what you mean by "is created as well but not displayed"?

Comment: If I try to make the output name variable, the feature class is created within the Geodatabase properly, with the "%Value%_FINAL" name but is not automatically displayed at the end of the tool. I could fix this by adding this feature class to the table of contents but the symbology doesn't appear as it should anyway.     
If I set a concrete name like.. "FINAL_LAYER" with no variable settings, the feature class displays at the end of the tool and the symbols show up as well. That's why I think is a name issue